# paypal not offering the option to pay without a paypal account

Tags: paypal

PayPal is not showing the option to pay with a debit/credit card when I set up the button using the following code.

I have checked with my client (who set up the PayPal account) who tell me that they have set up the business account, and have verified the email address.

I have taken out the sensitive bits, but everything is passing to PayPal correctly in the code (correct price, account details etc.) but only offers the option to login or create an account.

Have I missed anything in the code?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="paynow" name="paynow">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="webassist.dreamweaver.4_5_0" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@address.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value=<?php echo "Annual Meeting 2022 Attendee Registration for ".$DETAILS->getColumnVal("contact_name"); ?> />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo "ATT-".$DETAILS->getColumnVal("id"); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo($DETAILS->getColumnVal("total_cost")); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.thewebaddress.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo"https://www.thewebaddress.com/att_confirmation.php?id=".$DETAILS->getColumnVal("id"); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="receiver_email" value="email@address.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="mrb" value="code in here" />
<input type="hidden" name="pal" value="code in here" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg text-white" form="paynow" value="Submit">Proceed to Payment Screen</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option to pay as a guest within a PayPal Checkout page depends on many factors, and is never guaranteed. What you are describing is normal behavior that cannot be changed.

If you want to make a 'Debit or Credit Card' option always appear on your site, you can integrate the current PayPal Checkout buttons, which give a black button specifically for this.  See [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/), or a [demo code sample](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client).

Comment: I've been using this code in other websites, and it has never before blocked payment without an account being set up. Is this a new thing?

Comment: Part of it could be new, it always depends on many factors and there's no telling what may have changed. The black button has been the only guaranteed option for years, that's not new.

Comment: fair enough, thank you for the explanation and the link. I've started to use it and see how it works. Doe this mean I need to have access to each of my client's PayPal account to set this up?